# Checksum not matching while debugging

Tags: vb.net

I've just migrated my solution and a couple projects within it to a new server. Solution was deployed in vs 2010 and on the new server I have vs 2013. When I rebuilt it, no errors appear, but when I try to debug in some place, I get the below message that some checksum is not matching. What I did so far was to delete /bin folder and rebuild the project to which this .vb file belongs, and then again make a reference to it. Secondly I have tried to rebuild the whole project, but it seems it is still showing up.

```
Locating source for 'D:\Ins\Projects\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsSerializer.vb'. Checksum: MD5 {c6 47 d5 eb 7 fc 5a 8 e2 13 c e2 9b 73 57 5b}
Determining whether the checksum matches for the following locations:
1: D:\Ins\Projects\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsSerializer.vb Checksum: MD5 {1 3d 71 5 70 b8 e8 bf e0 e4 53 98 85 e5 6c c1} Checksum doesn't match.
The file 'D:\Ins\Projects\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsSerializer.vb' exists.
Looking in script documents for 'D:\Ins\Projects\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsSerializer.vb'...
Determining whether the checksum matches for the following locations:
1: D:\Ins\Projects\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsSerializer.vb Checksum: MD5 {1 3d 71 5 70 b8 e8 bf e0 e4 53 98 85 e5 6c c1} Checksum doesn't match.
Looking in the projects for 'D:\Ins\Projects\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsSerializer.vb'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
Looking in directory 'D:\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: D:\Ins\Projects\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsSerializer.vb.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'D:\Ins\Projects\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsLoader\GeneralSettingsSerializer.vb'.
```

Comment: i was able to do it by removing all bins directories for all my projects then rebuilt each by each and at last make again references. Unfortunetly now i got another problem since i add new code somwhere - when debugging it says that that no see class file which want to use and ask me to point to it... If i just fire up application it going well - BUT with older class version - how to avoid that issue that every time i add new code and make rebuilt/built it will be attached to existing projects? I didnt have that problem with VS 2010 but now with VS 2013 yes.

Comment: i tried with project order and dependency but not working for me. Now the only way it can work for me is to delete dll from certain project and make reference once again.. ;/